# How to use ontouchevent() with onitemclick Listener?

Tags: android, onitemclicklistener

I am trying to make horizontal scroll view for grid view. I am succeeded in with horizontal scroll view. But now i need to implement onItemClickListener too for the same grid view. I used GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener and onTouchEvent for horizontal scroll.If i use this onItemClickListener is not working. Con somebody help me to get both working. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I recently had to deal with the same issue and this is how I solved it.

Firstly, I override the default `onListItemClick` listener inside the ListFragment/ListActivity. Then in the `onTouchEvent` method, I set up a condition that when true, makes a call to the ListView's `onListItemClick`. This call is performed when the action is equal to `MotionEvent.ACTION_UP` and the condition was met. You must first decide what group of events constitute a click for your view. I declared mine as an `ACTION_DOWN` immediately followed by an `ACTION_UP`. When you are ready to perform the `onListItemClick`, your must pass the actual item's view, position and id to the method.

See my example below.

```
Class....{
    private boolean clickDetected = true;

    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        final int action = ev.getAction();
        final int x = (int) ev.getX();
        final int y = (int) ev.getY();

        //if an action other than ACTION_UP and ACTION_DOWN was performed
        //then we are no longer in a simple item click event group 
        //(i.e DOWN followed immediately by UP)
        if (action != MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
                && action != MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            clickDetected = false;

        if (action == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
            //check if the onItemClick requirement was met
            if (clickDetected){
                //get the item and necessary data to perform onItemClick
                //subtract the first visible item's position from the current item's position
                //to compensate for the list been scrolled since pointToPosition does not consider it
                int position = pointToPosition(x,y) - getFirstVisiblePosition();
                View view = getChildAt(position);
                if (view != null){//only continue if a valid view exists
                    long id = view.getId();
                    performItemClick(view, position, id);//pass control back to fragment/activity
                }//end if
            }//end if

            clickDetected= true;//set this to true to refresh for next event
        }//end if
        return super.onTouchEvent(ev);
        ....
    }//end onTouchEvent
}//end class
```

This setup allow for much flexibility, for example if you want to set up a long click you can do the same as above and simple check for the difference in time between the ACTION_DOWN and the ACTION_UP.

Another approach is to get the position of the item that initiated the action down and check it against the one for the action up and even throw in a time differential criteria for the down and up action (say less than 1 second).

Comment: Good aproach, this is something I was login for. Anyway, I would like to mention that this would not work on some low cost devices. I noticed not long ago while testing my new application that while on samsung, asus, gigabite (and so on, common devices) view registered ACTION_DOWN followed immediatelly by ACTION_UP action, on low cost devices it went as ACTION_DOWN -> ACTION_MOVE -> ACTION_UP.